# Getting Notified that a Virus Definition Update is Available for Microsoft Security Essentials

Tags: windows, security, anti-virus

I have to perform regular offline updates on Microsoft Security Essentials Virus definition files for a computer not hooked up to the internet.

I found the following KB article with a link to the offline file definitions:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971606

but the link does not say when the definition file was published.

Does Microsoft have a RSS feed, mailing list, or other communication method that I can sign up for so that I can know when definitions are updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the Microsoft Antimalware and Microsoft Antivirus definition RSS feeds at:

http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/RSS/UpdatesRSS.aspx

and

http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/RSS/UpdatesRSS.aspx?PackageType=AS

In your favorite reader to see about updates.

Answer (score 1):

Security essentials definitions are updated daily, sometimes several times a day. Those links in the article are updated daily also, they are the latest definitions.

I downloaded the 64bit version and did a properties on the file and it revealed it was modified 1-4-2012 (4:24pm)

.
[image]